# Books to learn Islamic Philosophy

Tags: ethics, reference-request, islamic-philosophy

I have for a long time wanted to study philosophy so I recently started reading Plato's dialogues like Crito, Apology and also have ordered Plato's Republic.

I want to study Islamic philosophy alongside Western philosophy. So I want to get like a comprehensive list of books to get myself learn Islamic Philosophy.

Thankyou.

Comment: Did you try the reference section in the [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_philosophy#Bibliography)?

Comment: Also https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/arabic-islamic-metaphysics/.

Comment: The Greeks and Romans were foundational for both Islamic and European thinking -- Socrates, Plato, and Aristotle will help with both.  Contemporary philosophic thinking is cross cultural, and provides a useful set of questions to probe unrecognized assumptions in Greek, Islamic, European Scholastic, and European Enlightenment thinking.  The linguicism and clarification of terms in analytic philosophy, and the focus on test/falsification/correction in philosophy of science are methods to question traditions.